# C# Sending String Array to C++ DLL as SafeArray. Gets only first character

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have C# project and I have to use a C++ dll using DllImport. (I have source codes of c++ dll)

I'm importing a function from c++ dll like this :

```
[DllImport("Example.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int SendRequest([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_BSTR)] ref string[] fields);
```

I'm using this function in C# like this :

```
List<String> fields = new List<String>();

fields.Add("Test1");
fields.Add("Test2");
string[] fieldsArr = fields.ToArray();

int resultOfSendRequest = SendRequest(ref fieldsArr);
```

Problem is in c++ dll, it casts string to char* in somewhere and it reads the only first character, not entire string.

How can I solve this without touching c++ dll. (If I call this function from VB6 it works without any problem.)

C++ code is like this :

```
VARIANT vVar;

 __declspec( dllexport ) int _stdcall SendRequest  (SAFEARRAY**);

int _stdcall SendRequest ( SAFEARRAY** arrayFlds,                           
                           short NFlds)  
{   
    // *********** prepare O.i.d, fields name, values
    for (long iElem=0;  iElem < NFlds;  iElem++)
        if (LoadElement (&vVar, iElem, &flds[iElem], &pFlds[iElem],*arrayFlds)==-1)
            return -1;

    //...
}




int LoadElement( VARIANT*   vVar,                
                 long       iElem, 
                 S_FLDS*    flds,
                 char**     pFld, 
                 SAFEARRAY* arrayFlds)
{
    hRes = SafeArrayGetElement(arrayFlds, &iElem, pFld);   

    strcpy(flds->FieldName, *pFld);
    flds->bValLen = 0;

    char *Name = flds->FieldName;

    //....
}
```

The fieldName and char *Name at the end of the core only consists of first character of string. Not the full string.

Comment: One the issues I see here is that the unmanaged code appears to modify its behaviour depending on whether it is being called from VB or otherwise. That's rather freaky and makes me doubt that things are what they seem. Can you produce a simple [mcve] for us?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Okay, i simplified the code. While debugging i can see that, in LoadElement() function SAFEARRAY* arrayFlds has all the strings i sent from c# code. And char** pFld has the first character. But in the end 'fieldName' and 'char *Name' has only the first character, not all string. Note that if i use this dll from VB6 there is no problem. It looks like VB6 string array is not same with c# array string. I don't want to modify c++ dll. I should fix this in c# code .I'm not very good at c++ programming. Maybe this can be easily solved i dont know.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]

Comment: Okay, while i'm working on 'Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example'. Can you explain me please why if i call this function from VB6 i'm seeing chinese characters in Safearrays and it's working, but if i call this from c# i'm seeing exact strings i sent in Safearrays and it's not working. It looks like encoding issue.

Comment: The Chinese is a classic symptom of 8 bit ANSI text being interpreted as UTF16.

Comment: I edited my question. I can clearly say i can't send the same string[] i send from vb6 code. How can i do this ?

Comment: I can't see a [mcve]. Sorry, but I can't help you.

Answer (score -3):

In C Langues a string is a byte[] with each string terminated with a '\0'.  An array of strings the last item has two '\0' at the end.  So try following :

```
        [DllImport("Example.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int SendRequest(IntPtr fields);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<String> fields = new List<String>();

            fields.Add("Test1");
            fields.Add("Test2");

            string fieldsArr = string.Join("\0", fields);
            IntPtr fieldsPtr = Marshal.StringToBSTR(fieldsArr);
            int results = SendRequest(fieldsPtr);

        }
```

---

If it is an array of pointers then use this

```
       public struct Pointers
        {
            public IntPtr[] pointers;
        }

        [DllImport("Example.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int SendRequest(IntPtr fields);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<String> fields = new List<String>();

            fields.Add("Test1");
            fields.Add("Test2");

            List<IntPtr> pointers = new List<IntPtr>();

            foreach (string field in fields)
            {
                IntPtr intPtr = Marshal.StringToBSTR(field);
                pointers.Add(intPtr);
            }

            Pointers sPointers = new Pointers();
            sPointers.pointers = pointers.ToArray();

            IntPtr fieldsPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(sPointers, fieldsPtr, true);
            int results = SendRequest(fieldsPtr);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(fieldsPtr);

        }
```

Comment: But i need to send a SafeArray.

Comment: In c++ dll, it uses hRes = SafeArrayAccessData  (*arrayFlds, (void**)&pData);

Comment: If i use your code hRes = "E_UNEXPECTED Catastrophic failure."

Comment: The MarshalString.BSTR creates a safe array (in unmanaged space).  It looks like the function want two parameters :  arrayFlds and pData.  What is pData?

Comment: It's just created before that function.  BYTE* pData;

Comment: I added the full code (only excluded unnecessary ones), the 'FieldName' at the end of the code only consists of the first character of string. Not the full string.

Comment: @jdweng No, it's a `SAFEARRAY`, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ec8025b-4763-4526-ab45-390c5d8b3b1e(vs.85)  If you've never done any C#/COM interop before then this may not be the question for you.

Comment: Isn't a SafeArray in c++ the same as using in c# Marshal.StructureToPtr().